# Karma + Jasmine + Ionic Concurrency

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, jasmine, karma-runner

I am doing unit tests with Karma/Jasmine for a ionic app. I have a .js called initApp.js with this code:

```
function initFactoryString() {
    if (angular.isUndefined(thiz.string_list)) {
        $http.get(url + 'strings/strings.json').success(function (response) {
            $rootScope.static_strings = response;
        });
    }
};

ionic.Platform.ready(function () {
    initFactoryString();
});
```

initFactoryString() load a JSON file with the strings of the app. On the other hand, I have a jasmine test for a webservices factory with specs like this:

```
it('Petición sin fechas', function() {
        $httpBackend.expectGET('urlService').respond('dataResponse');
        $webServices.getAvailableDates(1234);
        $httpBackend.flush();
});
```

If I execute Karma, appear this error:

```
Error: Unexpected request: GET strings/strings.json
Expected GET urlService
```

It's obvious that the problem  is about js concurrency because initApp.js was executed before my jasmine test but the response is solved meanwhile the test run. How can I do for, in case of test, disable the initFactoryString() call automaticaly?

Comment: You should either mock `$http.get(url + 'strings/strings.json')` reqyest or stub `ionic.Platform.ready`. Files like `initApp.js` shouldn't be included in this test at all (and Ionic possibly too).

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```
$httpBackend.when('GET','urlService').respond('dataResponse');
```

Comment: Would you mind adding an explanation to make us understand what your code does?

Comment: Thank you for you response, I solved with this: `var strings = readJSON('www/strings/strings.json');   
     $httpBackend.when('GET','strings/strings.json').respond(strings);`

Comment: "when" is the condition when you may make a http call whereas in expect you have to make a call since you have a if condition so you may or may not make a http call that's why using when is preferred in conditional statements.